# Check if Ruby request response is gzip encoded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On `Net::HTTP.Get` request to a URL with `accept-encoding` header set as `gzip`, how do I check if the response is gzipped, before calling `Zlib` unzipping on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, doing a `response['Content-Encoding']` returns `gzip` if the response is Gzip encoded and nil otherwise. Discovered the param value by inspecting the browser HTTP response headers.